# How to add a condition between two DateTime's using only hours and minutes in C#?

Tags: c#

I am trying to code a hotel management system in **ASP.NET MVC** and I have to code a method that forbids you from adding an employee to database between hours **1:00PM** and **3:00PM** everyday.

I am very unfamiliar with *Datetime* types in C# and this is what I have:

```
var hour1 = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm");
hour1.setHour("1:00PM");

var hour2 = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm");
hour2.setHour("3:00PM");


   if (DateTime.Now >= hour1 && DateTime.Now <= hour2 )
      {
            //do stuff
      }
   else
      {
            //do stuff
      }
```

I know **setHour** doesn't even exist in the *Datetime* context but this is only an example to show what I am trying to achieve. I cant find a solution in the whole internet.

Comment: As per **itsme86's** comment beneath my question, are you only interested in whole hours or minutes too?   Is there a cut-off for example for say 3:15?  (Your title seems to imply it but your question's body and code sample only shows between 1:00 PM and 3:00 PM)

Comment: Well when I said 1:00PM, it already has the minutes " :00 " but I think it doesn't matter because your solution provides the exact time. No there are not cut-offs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> that forbids you from adding an employee to database between hours 1:00PM and 3:00PM everyday

There is no need to convert to a `string`.  Just use the [`.Hour`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.hour?view=netframework-4.8#System_DateTime_Hour) property.

MSDN:

> Gets the hour component, expressed as a value between 0 and 23.

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
const int onePM = 13;
const int threePM = 15;

if (now.Hour >= onePM && now.Hour < threePM)
{
    // do stuff
}
else
{
    // do stuff
}
```

**NOTE:** This is a very simple example that is taking advantage of comparing time to whole hours only based on the body of OP’s question and code sample.   It **won’t** work if say you had a cutoff for **3:15 PM** as my code doesn’t include minutes.

This is based on the discussion below in comments.

**UPDATE**

OP:

> Well when I said 1:00PM, it already has the minutes " :00 " but I think it doesn't matter because your solution provides the exact time. No there are not cut-offs.

Excellent, thanks.

Comment: This solution is slightly complicated by the inclusion of minutes as specified in the question's title.

Comment: @itsme86 what do you mean?  Hour only returns a value in the range 0-23

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't allow OP to specify minutes. It sounds like the start time could potentially be something like 1:15PM, for instance.

Comment: Decomplicated: use `now.TimeOfDay` and compare against constructed `TimeSpan` instances: e.g. `new TimeSpan(13, 15, 0)`.

Comment: Tried this code but onePM and threePM does not even returns the minutes, just returns "13" and "15".

Comment: I think it would be the same "13" as "13:00", tried to change my time and it worked.

Comment: @itsme86 ah yes I see thanks.  I agree about the title but the body of the question seems to imply just hours.  I shall clarify with OP

Comment: @madreflection yes that's great too!

Answer (score 2):

A simple extension method like this one should do it:

```
static class DateTimeExtensionMethods
{
    public static bool IsBetween(this DateTime source, TimeSpan lowerBound, TimeSpan upperBound)
    {
        return source >= source.Date.Add(lowerBound)
            && source <= source.Date.Add(upperBound);
    }
}
```

Test code:

```
var tests = new string[]
    {
        "2019-01-01 12:00 pm",
        "2019-01-01 01:00 pm",
        "2019-01-01 02:30 pm",
        "2019-01-01 03:00 pm",
        "2019-01-01 03:30 pm"
    };

var dates = tests.Select(s => DateTime.Parse(s));

foreach (var d in dates)
{
    var result = d.IsBetween(TimeSpan.Parse("13:00"), TimeSpan.Parse("15:00"));
    if (result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} is between 1:00 and 3:00", d);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} is not between 1:00 and 3:00", d);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1/1/2019 12:00:00 PM is not between 1:00 and 3:00
1/1/2019 1:00:00 PM is between 1:00 and 3:00
1/1/2019 2:30:00 PM is between 1:00 and 3:00
1/1/2019 3:00:00 PM is between 1:00 and 3:00
1/1/2019 3:30:00 PM is not between 1:00 and 3:00
```

Link to [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0iX0YL)

Comment: I think this will be a big problem if the employee changes the date from the server and he will be able to add employees between that time.

Comment: You could just compare the bounds to `source.TimeOfDay` instead.